# ASP.NET MultiLine TextBox - RegularExpressionValidator for MaxLength with NewLine (\r\n) - Difference in Client & Server Side Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

**Background:** I am working on a ASP.NET webpage and I have a multiline textbox as below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

and a regular expression validator to check the max length as below

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,10}$" ErrorMessage="You can only enter a maximum of 10 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The idea is to restrict the user input to max 10 characters. As you may be aware, the `RegularExpressionValidator` does both client side and server side validation.

**The problem:** For user inputs with new line character, the client side character count seems to be less than the server side character count. Due to this, it passes client side validation but fails on the server side validation.

This is potentially because on the client side new line character is `\n` and on the server side it is `\r\n`.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Please note I need both client side and server side validation.

**Test Data:**

```
Line
Line1
```

**UPDATE:**
Apart from the above weirdness, there are few more with the way `\r\n` is handled by .Net

1. If the text containing `\r\n` is passed through `.Net web service` it
   is serialized as `\n` automatically. So the count/length of the
   string containing `\r\n` varies before and after the `web service`
   call.
2. If the same text containing `\r\n` is stored in `SQL Server` then it retains `\r\n` as it is.

So depending on the how the value from `MultiLine TextBox` is processed further, the validation logic needs to change. In my case, the `string` is passed through a `web service` before reaching an external system - so the `regex` suggested by @sln works well on both `client and server side validation`.

But if you are storing the value directly in `SQL Server` and looking to validate the `string` using `regex` then additional steps like replacing `\r\n` with `\n` and vice versa when reading and displaying from database is required.

Perhaps, this whole approach of validating max length characters is a case of [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem where there could be a more elegant way of doing this in the first place?

Comment: use regex on server side to remove unwanted characters and then validate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to run on both sides  `^(?:\S|[^\S\r\n]|\r?\n){0,10}$`

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      \S              # Not whitespace
   |  [^\S\r\n]       # or, whitespace, not CR or LF
   |  \r? \n          # or, CR(optional)LF
 ){0,10}
 $
```

Newline only -

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 10 ) 
Line
Line1
```

CRLF

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 11 ) 
Line
Line1
```

*Updated:*
**CRLF Translation Helpers**

I find these routines to be the fastest on the Planet.
They are single pass regex and can do huge megabyte conversions in an instant.
This pseudo-code is in a C++ paradigm.

```
// To Normalize to CRLF 
// -------------------------
// regex  CRLFCRtoCRLF( "(?>\\r\\n?)|\\n" ); // Dot-Net style
regex  CRLFCRtoCRLF( "\\r\\n?+|\\n" ); // Pcre/Perl style

void ReplaceCRLFCRtoCRLF( string& strSrc, string& strDest )
{
    string repl = "\\r\\n";
    strDest = regex_replace( strSrc, CRLFCRtoCRLF, repl );
}


// To Normalize to LF 
// -------------------------
regex  CRLFCRtoLF( "\\r\\n|\\r(?!\\n)" );

void ReplaceCRLFCRtoLF( string& strSrc, string& strDest )
{
    string repl = "\\n";
    strDest = regex_replace( strSrc, CRLFCRtoLF, repl );
}


// To find current state (not really needed)
// (Returns true if standalone CR or LF)
// ------------------------------------------
regex  CRorLF( "\\A(?>[^\\r\\n]*)(?>(?:\\r\\n)+[^\\r\\n]*)*\\z" );

bool IsLoneCRorLF( string& strSrc )
{
    // In this case we are going to try to match an entire
    // string that is free of lone cr's or lf's.
    // Then return the negative of that.
    // This is much faster than using the lookround's,
    // and we need a little speed here.
    return !regex_search( strSrc, CRorLF );
}
```

Comment: @TonyStark - Hey no problem. I saw your update, added a couple of pseudo code helper functions that do translations to/from.